# How show details of an item when recycleview button is clicked in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have items in database that have id, name, description, image.  I am pulling it and displaying the name as button using Recycleview in Kicy

```
class ItemsView(RecycleView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ItemsView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.load_data()


    def load_data(self, *args):

    
        c = mydb.cursor()

        c.execute("SELECT id, name, description FROM items")

        list_data = []
        for item in c:
            list_data.append({'text': item[1], 'id': item[0], 'desc': item[2]})
```

In .kv file

```
<ItemsView>:
    viewclass: 'Button'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        color: 1,1,1,1
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

So far I have the names as button. When I click on that button, I want to display a new screen which shows that particular items description and image. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `data` of the `RecycleView`, you can specify any property of the `viewclass`. Since your `viewclass` is a `Button`, you can add `on_release` to the `data`. Something like this:

```
    for item in c:
        list_data.append({'text': item[1], 'id': item[0], 'desc': item[2], 'on_release': partial(self.doit, item)})
```

The above arranges for each of the `Buttons` to call a `doit()` method of your
`ItemsView` class with an argument of the `item`.

Then you can add the `doit()` method to the `ItemsView()` class:

```
def doit(self, item):
    print('in doit:', item)
```

Obviously, you can do anything you want inside the `doit()` method.